# Как сделать красивый фрейм данных из XML?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, pandas, обработка-данных

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Данные>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> nan </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1074 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.1 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 0 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> nan </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1075 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.2 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 0 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> nan </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1076 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.3 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 0 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 1 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1074 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL10741 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.1.1 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1074 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL10742 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.1.2 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1075 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1090 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.2.1 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1075 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1099 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.2.2 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1075 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1101 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.2.3 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 1 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1099 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1147 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.3.1.2 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 2 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1099 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1170 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.3.1.3 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 2 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 1 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1099 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1193 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.3.1.4 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 2 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
</Данные>
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [данным решением](http://www.austintaylor.io/lxml/python/pandas/xml/dataframe/2016/07/08/convert-xml-to-pandas-dataframe/):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

class XML2DataFrame:

    def __init__(self, xml_data):
        self.root = ET.XML(xml_data)

    def parse_root(self, root):
        return [self.parse_element(child) for child in iter(root)]

    def parse_element(self, element, parsed=None):
        if parsed is None:
            parsed = dict()
        for key in element.keys():
            parsed[key] = element.attrib.get(key)
        if element.text:
            parsed[element.tag] = element.text
        for child in list(element):
            self.parse_element(child, parsed)
        return parsed

    def process_data(self):
        structure_data = self.parse_root(self.root)
        return pd.DataFrame(structure_data)

xml2df = XML2DataFrame(xml_data)
df = xml2df.process_data()
```

---

Пример:

```
xml_data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Данные>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> nan </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1074 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.1 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 0 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> nan </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1075 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.2 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 0 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> nan </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1076 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.3 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 0 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 1 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1074 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL10741 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.1.1 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1074 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL10742 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.1.2 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1075 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1090 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.2.1 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1075 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1099 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.2.2 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1075 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1101 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.2.3 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 1 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 1 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1099 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1147 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.3.1.2 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 2 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1099 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1170 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.3.1.3 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 2 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 1 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
    <Каталог>
        <Код_родительского_раздела_каталога> CL1099 </Код_родительского_раздела_каталога>
        <Код_раздела_каталога> CL1193 </Код_раздела_каталога>
        <Название_раздела_каталога> Название 0.3.1.4 </Название_раздела_каталога>
        <Уровень_иерархии> 2 </Уровень_иерархии>
        <Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture> 0 </Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture>
    </Каталог>
</Данные>"""

df = XML2DataFrame(xml_data).process_data()
```

Результат:

```
In [346]: df
Out[346]:
       Каталог Код_раздела_каталога Код_родительского_раздела_каталога Название_раздела_каталога  \
0   \n                      CL1074                                nan              Название 0.1
1   \n                      CL1075                                nan              Название 0.2
2   \n                      CL1076                                nan              Название 0.3
3   \n                     CL10741                             CL1074            Название 0.1.1
4   \n                     CL10742                             CL1074            Название 0.1.2
..         ...                  ...                                ...                       ...
6   \n                      CL1099                             CL1075            Название 0.2.2
7   \n                      CL1101                             CL1075            Название 0.2.3
8   \n                      CL1147                             CL1099          Название 0.3.1.2
9   \n                      CL1170                             CL1099          Название 0.3.1.3
10  \n                      CL1193                             CL1099          Название 0.3.1.4

   Пометка_удаления_раздела_в_ClearFuture Уровень_иерархии
0                                      0                0
1                                      0                0
2                                      1                0
3                                      0                1
4                                      0                1
..                                    ...              ...
6                                      0                1
7                                      1                1
8                                      0                2
9                                      1                2
10                                     0                2

[11 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии 1.3.0 в Pandas была добавлена функция [pd.read_xml()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html):

```
df = pd.read_xml(xml)
```